# 'class Adafruit_SPIDevice' has no member named 'endTransaction'

Tags: library, spi, adafruit

So what I have done is followed all of the instructions in the following link:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pygamer/setup
and have managed to get all the way up to https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pygamer/arduino-libraries.

the board not has its own serial COM port and does work with a very basic blink example program which does not include any libraries at all. Shown on https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pygamer/using-with-arduino-ide.

The next problem occuring is that now another error message is coming up within the code which I am not too sure it is trying to say:
`Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_EPD\src\Adafruit_EPD.cpp: In member function 'void Adafruit_EPD::csHigh()':` 
and
`libraries\Adafruit_EPD\src\Adafruit_EPD.cpp:649:12: error: 'class Adafruit_SPIDevice' has no member named 'endTransaction'`.

Here is the github for the library I am using (its called adafruit arcada library), https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Arcada.

Here is the code that I am trying to run using the adafruit_arcada library. I have checked it is installed in the right place in the arduino/library folder on the computer system.

Here is my code I am trying to run:

```
#include "Adafruit_Arcada.h"
Adafruit_Arcada arcada;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Hello! Arcada TFT Test");

  // Start TFT and fill black
  if (!arcada.arcadaBegin()) {
    Serial.print("Failed to begin");
    while (1) delay(10);
  }
  arcada.displayBegin();
  
  // Turn on backlight
  arcada.setBacklight(255); 
}

void loop() {
  arcada.display->fillScreen(ARCADA_RED);
#if defined(ADAFRUIT_MONSTER_M4SK_EXPRESS)
  arcada.display2->fillScreen(ARCADA_RED);
#endif

  delay(100);

  arcada.display->fillScreen(ARCADA_GREEN);
#if defined(ADAFRUIT_MONSTER_M4SK_EXPRESS)
  arcada.display2->fillScreen(ARCADA_GREEN);
#endif

  delay(100);

  arcada.display->fillScreen(ARCADA_BLUE);
#if defined(ADAFRUIT_MONSTER_M4SK_EXPRESS)
  arcada.display2->fillScreen(ARCADA_BLUE);
#endif

  delay(100);

  arcada.display->fillScreen(ARCADA_BLACK);
#if defined(ADAFRUIT_MONSTER_M4SK_EXPRESS)
  arcada.display2->fillScreen(ARCADA_BLACK);
#endif

  delay(100);
}
```

However, something is telling me that something is either out of date or I might have potentially installed something wrong because in the guide that was sent there is 5 examples within the adafruit arcada library. But with the one I have installed, there is lots of examples. The guide itself was not updated too long ago (6th November 2020). The arcada library I have installed is the one installed from the library manger and the version of the library is 2.5.0 and the one on the tutorial on https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pygamer/arduino-libraries seems to be saying the library is version 1.0.0. Perhaps the library is too update on my computer to date compared to the one in the guide which potentially might be more out of date than the one I have on my computer.

Comment: The [line in your error message](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_EPD/blob/4.2.0/src/Adafruit_EPD.cpp#L649) seems to be referring to a library for ["Adafruit E-paper displays"](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_EPD).  Did I miss something in your question that should have clued me into why an e-paper display plays a role in this?

Comment: Well... I am not too sure if the screen is a E-paper display.

Comment: But I did look at the adafruit EPD driver and it seemed to be out of date so I updated it.

Comment: The display used on the [board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4242) is described as "1.8" 160x128 Color TFT", "TFT" being an LCD technology.  Mostly I was wondering if you'd added anything or if there was a mini-display or battery indicator something of that sort that would account for it.  EPD library is mentioned as a [dependency of Arcada](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Arcada/blob/2.5.0/library.properties#L10), for what reason I don't know.  It'll be a while before I get a deeper look into it.

Comment: Don't worry I have solved it, all that I did was update the EPD driver and that was it.

Comment: Post what you did as an answer to your own question.